# Subscripting text in matplotlib labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, output, subscript

this is my first question and I am a noob at python. So probably more to follow...

I would like to create a figure with matplotlib. In the labels, I would like to include a chemical formula, which involves subscripts (I think the same would work for superscripts...).

Anyway, I have no idea, how the label would have to look like.

```
import numpy as nu
import pylab as plt

x = nu.array([1,2,3,4])
y = nu.array([1,2,3,4])

plt.plot(x,y, label='H2O')
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.show()
```

Ok, this gives me a plot with the label "H2O". How can I subscript the "2" in the label, as is common for chemical formulae?

I searched the web, but I didn't find anything useful yet.

I figured that I could use

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc['text', usetex=True]
```

but I don't want to use it (I know how to use LaTeX, but I don't want here).

Another option is:

```
label='H$_2$O'
```

but this changes the font (math).

There MUST be a way, how does subscripting in matplotlib-legends work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Try to change this line

```
plt.plot(x,y, label='H2O')
```

for this:

```
plt.plot(x,y, label='$H_2O$')
```

It shows with the font math.

Or also you can use the unicode character for that: ₂ (0xE2 / ₂)

```
plt.plot(x,y, label=u'H₂O')
```

or instead:

```
plt.plot(x,y, label=u"H\u2082O")
```

Please, note that unicode strings are noted as u"" instead than "".

Comment: thanks, I already tried this (in the meantime). It returns in a different style than lables etc...
Is there really no simple way without changing the style?

Comment: label=u'H\2082O'

returns something weird...
Sorry, I have no idea how to use unicode here...in your code line, the "2" is somewhat smaller ans subscripted, how did you do this?

Comment: Simply copy the line. Anyway, I got this looking on charmap utility (I'm on linux, but under Windows should works too. It has a charmap)

Comment: yes, I copied. But it returns a box for the subscripted "2"...
I added
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
but it remains the same.
Something with the font?

Comment: Other solution is using that (i just discovered): u"\u2082". This returns a subscript 2

Comment: yes, I tried this one as well. Still shows the box. Seems that I need to change the font.

    from matplotlib import rc 
    rc('font', **{'family':'sans-serif', 'sans-serif' ['Helvetica']})

error: font-family not found.
Changing Helvetica to Arial works without error, but still writes the box instead of subscripted 2

Comment: Try other font with more unicode char support, like cambria or calibri [more](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/fontsupport.htm)